# Laravel 5.5 "The file must be an image" on image array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.5 project which is giving me some issues... One of them is that when I upload some image it returns me an error: "**The file must be an image**" with the following code in the controller.`

```
public function update(\App\Property $property, Request $request)
{
    $rules = [ 
        'images.*' => 'mimes:image|max:2048',
        'zone' => 'required'
    ];

    $messages = [
        'images.mimes' => 'The file must be an image', // in my file that is a translated of the original message
        'images.max' => 'The images sizes must be under 2MB',
    ];

 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        parent::message(
            $validator->errors(),
            '¡Error!',
            'error'
        );

        return back()->withInput();
    }
```

> **Just in case:**
>
> I was reading some people who had the same issue but in my case I have the usual `<form method="POST action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I made a `dd($request->files)` on the request but the all the images I upload seems to be images.

Also I've tried to use the iteration method as following:

```
    if($request->hasFile('images')) {
        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $validator = Validator::make(
                [ 'image' => $image ], 
                [ 'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048' ],
                [ 
                    'image.mimes' => 'Images must have format (JPEG, PNG, JPG, GIF or SVG)',
                    'image.max' => 'Each image must be under 2MB' 
                ]);

            if($validator->fails()) {
                parent::message(
                    $validator->errors(),
                    '¡Error!',
                    'error'
                );

                return back()->withInput();
            }
        }
    }
```

But when the images are too bigger than 2MB the request is not even passing through `if($request->hasFile() function`.
And I want a generic error for all the images and not validate every image, is that possible? By the way in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays) it hasn't the previous iterating method.

Comment: try this `'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png',`

Comment: I'll try... but I thought they were equal...

Comment: Oh, I saw one error, I wrote `mime:image`.

Comment: try it, let me know

Comment: although now it's working, Bigger files than 2MB gets error "The images.0 has failed to upload" while I defined the custom messages for *max* and *image* or *mime*.

Comment: I think 2MB is the default max payload size defined in the PHP config, so you need to increase that or use a different way such as chunking or a different protocol that is more stream/buffer-like.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to figure this out as well and it seems symfony has been updated since Laravel 5.5. On Laravel 8 I can tell you that the following combination of settings fixed the error I had yielding the same error type you had:
In your form:
make sure your form has

```
<form method="POST action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In your validator:

```
'image' =>  'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
```

Comment: yes, always when passing a file from a form in your web view or HTML always make sure to add the enctype as this allows file and any other non textual information to be passed to your logic for processing.

Comment: You mean even without `'image.*' (which is for multiple images)`, is this going to still work ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and fixed it by changing image to file and specifying image file types.

```
'images' => 'file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
```

In your case,

```
$rules = [ 
        'images.*' => 'file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        'zone' => 'required'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you are using Laravel Collectives for your form, then you can implement the enctype as show below :

```
{!! Form::open([‘action’ =>’ProfilesController@update’, 
‘method’ => ‘POST’, ‘enctype’ => ‘multipart/form-data’]) !!}
```